# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:analyze-only (default)

Tags: java, spring, maven

I did mvn clean install -DskipTests and I am getting this error. Tried everything, still  it is not resolved till now.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:analyze-only (default) on project p3: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:analyze-only failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:analyze-only (default) on project p3: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.9:analyze-only failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: It looks like you configured the plugin in your pom file wrong `:2.9:analyze-only failed.: IllegalArgumentException -> [`... Apart  from that I strongly recommend to upgrade https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/